# My Site creation failure for user after moving My Sites to dedicated web application

Tags: security, my-site, user-profile-service, managed-path

I have created a new web application at port 8080 with the intention of having all personal site creation (i.e. My Sites) stored in a dedicated WSS_Content database (i.e. a best practice recommendation).

I've gone through all the steps needed, I think:

- created **MySitesCollection** using **Enterprise Template "My Site Host"** at root of `http://SPstaff:8080` and this top-level site was successfully created
- Enabled self-service site creation for the web application (changed radio button to ON). I got a **Warning: Self-Service Site Creation will create sites under a shared host name** which I didn't understand (maybe relevant?)
- Added a managed path **/mysites** to this web app
- Configured My Site settings for the User Profile service application by clicking *Setup My Sites* such that **My Site Host** set to `http://spstaff:8080/` and **Personal Site Location** set to mysites.

When I first tried browsing to SPstaff:8080/mysites/ I got a reasonable error in Windows Event Log:

```
Cannot open database "WSS_Content_SPSTAFFMySites" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'CBMIWEB\spAppPool'
```

So I added this user to this newly created database and I no longer get that error.

Instead, I am getting errors like this sequence:

**First error is Event ID: 6141 Task Category: Topology**

```
The site /mysites/joanc could not be created.  The following exception occurred: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation
```

Next entry in Application Log is Event ID: 5187 Task Category: Administration

```
My Site creation failure for user 'CBMIWEB\joanc' for site url `'http://spstaff:8080/mysites/joanc'`. 
The exception was: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteCreateException: A failure was encountered while attempting to create the site. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionMask)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.ValidateSecurityOnOperation(SPOperationCode code, SPSecurableObject obj)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.AddRowToFeaturesTable(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtSite>b__9()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken, Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtSite(Byte[]& userToken, Guid& tranLockerId, Int32 nZone, Guid databaseid, Guid siteid, String sFeatures)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SscCreateSite(Guid gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, String bstrServerRelativeUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPContentDatabase database, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, String quotaTemplate, String sscRootWebUrl, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SelfServiceCreateSite(String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String contactLogin, String contactName, String contactEmail, String quotaTemplate, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateSite>b__0()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateSite>b__0()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.CreateSite(String strRequestUrl, Boolean bCollision, Int32 lcid)
```

Other symptoms using my personal logon browsing to `http://spstaff:8080/mysites/johna` are  the un-helpful "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: So there are a couple things I see. First why create the web app on a port (8080) rather than port 80? Second is your my site managed path an explicit managed path? Usually the personla managed path is a wildcard MP under the explicit MP (If you configure it that way.) My preference, though, is to use the root for the My Site Host and then create the personal managed path under that.

Comment: I would look at the perms for the DB. You may have added one user, but does the application pool user have all the rights it needs to the DB?

Comment: @Matthew McDermott - Thanks for your input. My intent for choosing a different port (rather than 80) was to isolate all MySite content in a separate content database. My managed path for mysites has always been of the wildcard type. Are you saying I could have achieved a separate content database for this new web app using the same port 80 as my default Sharepoint - 80? That is, are you saying I could have 2 content DBs (2 web apps) - Sharepoint - 80 and SharepointMySites - 80 (with the latter defined with one managed path?). Ultimately, the port did me in (see my answer below).

Comment: Yes, you only need a different host header. You get separation of content DBs with the new web application. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- My setup for this was generally OK but my choices for the new web application introduced a need for "host headers" and an arbitrary port of 8080
- The name requiring "host headers" required unneccessary complication so the entire web application was deleted
- This new web application still failed (even after all the proper steps taken)
- Captured HTTP traffic with Fiddler2 and errors led me to suspect Firewall(s) rules
- **Ultimately, the Windows Firewall on our Sharepoint server needed a new rule added for Inbound traffic (to allow port 81)**.

So the objective has been achieved but I wonder if I could have avoided using a different port number? Could I have added a 2nd web application (to achieve the separation of content to a diffent database) that also used port 80? Could a wildcard managed path for mysites at the root of this 2nd web app have been sufficient?

Comment: Nice work finding the answer to your question. 

This may work for the second question you raise: http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/create-second-web-application-using-the-default-port-80-in-sharepoint2010/
 - same solution sung by another artist - 
http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2012/10/setup-multiple-sharepoint-web.html